# Find number of some entity type

Tags: sparql

What is sparql query that finds count of some entity? For examles, on Linked movie database, if I want find count of actors or films, how can I get it?

I tried this

```
SELECT (count ( ?Film)){?entity rdf:type ?Film}
```

but got wrong number.

Comment: How do you know it returned the wrong number?  Where did you run this?  What did you expect it to be?

Comment: I've create some RDF graph for my own project, so I konw how many entites of some kind I put. I'm trying to get something similar to this website 
  http://wiki.linkedmdb.org/Main/Statistics
part  "Sample entites" but on my database.

Comment: Did my answer help?  Right now you're asking for anything of any type, and counting all the types.  Your variable names make it look like you're trying to count all the things of a particular type.

Comment: Yes, I want count of particular things, which I use in the most of other queries. For examle, on the link above says that exist 50000 Actors, I want only that number get on my entity

Comment: Well, at the moment, you're counting the types of everything that has a type.  E.g., since variable names are arbitrary, your query is the same as `select (count(?type) as ?numTypes) { ?thing a ?type }`.  Do you see the problem?

Comment: I finaly get I was looking for, thanks for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a whole lot missing from this question (e.g., where you ran the query, what you expected as a result, etc.) but I think we can pinpoint the problem even without those details.  First, let's rewrite your query using proper syntax (the formatting is optional;  the important thing is `count(?Film) as ?count`):

```
select (count(?Film) as ?count) {
  ?entity rdf:type ?Film
}
```

`?Film` here is a variable, so you're asking "find me things and their types, and then count how many types were found."  If you were trying to count the number of things of some particular film type, though, you probably wanted a query like:

```
select (count(?entity) as ?numberOfFilms) {
  ?entity rdf:type :Film .
}
```

Where `:Film` is some *particular* IRI, not a variable.  Also note that you can abbreviate `rdf:type` with `a`, so you can make this even shorter and fit it nicely on one line again, if you want:

```
select (count(?entity) as ?numberOfFilms) { ?entity a :Film }
```